# How can i display a video/DVD with subtitles on a video projector using VLC player?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles, projector

I am using the VLC player to watch DVDs on a notebook.
Subtitles are shown in the video ON THE NOTEBOOK,
but using my Dell video projector to display the video i see the video but no subtitles at all.

**What can i do to make subtitles work using the video projector?**

Comment: Does the video projector have a lower resolution than the screen? If so, the text might simply have "fallen off" the screen.

Comment: that might be an idea - ich will check that

Comment: Do you know which video-out module you're using.  You can find out by setting the message window to verbosity=2 and look for the line "looking for vout display module".  The video module should be listed shortly after that line.  You can also manually set the video output module in the Video settings.

Answer (score 2):

Two workarounds:

- Try setting the graphics card display mode in **clone mode**, so the exact same screen is displayed on the projector as on your monitor. Set the resolution to the highest value that both projector and monitor can display. *Should work around any possible dual-display issues in VLC, but might not be an optimal long term solution.*
- Change position of the subtitle in VLC preferences, **Subtitle/OSD > Force subtitle position**, try a negative number like -200 and see if it helps. *This would work around an off-screen placement of the subtitles caused by the projector being set to the wrong resolution, or a erroneous size of the VLC window.*

Comment: i have set my display cloned - this works fine with my classic media player (which shows subtitles using the projector). for VLC it does not work. even trying with several negative numbers in the subtitles settings did not help. any other suggestions?

Comment: That is strange indeed, clone mode is supposed to show the exact same picture in both screens, regardless of software... I will have to think about this...
What are your respective resolutions set to for the screen and projector?
What model is your graphics card? Are there any other noticeable differences between the screen and projector?